# make div always appear directly above another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm centering a div using...

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", (($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
    this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 
                                            $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
}
```

I'd then like to move another div to directly above this centered div so that they would sit as follows...

```
  |-------------|
  | Moved Above |
  |-------------|
  |             |
  |   Centered  |
  |             |
  |-------------|
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/) functions to put the new content on top of the current.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
var offs = $("#centered").offset();
$("#movedabove").css({
  left: offs.left()+"px",
  bottom: offs.top()+"px"
});
```

But I agree the previous answer is more practical.